# Subset of Invertible Elements a Group

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is the entire question: Let S be a set with an associative law of composition and with an identity element. Show that the subset $S^∗ \subset S$ consisting of all invertible elements is a group.

I can easily show that $S^∗$ contains the identity and that each inverse has an inverse in $S^∗$.  I also know that associativity comes from $S$.  However, where I'm stuck is trying to show closure.

My first approach was to take two elements $a,b \in S^∗$.  Then these have inverses, say $a',b' \in S^∗$.  Then the inverse of $ab$ is just $b'a'$ because $$(ab)(b'a')=a(bb')a'=aea'=aa'=e$$

However, I don't see how it's obvious that ab belongs to $S$ in the first place.  If $ab$ doesn't belong to $S$, it can't belong to $S^∗$.

Comment: Usually $S$ having a law of composition means that $ab \in S$ for all $a, b \in S$.

Answer (score 0):

So, as you wrote $S$ is a '*set with an associative law of composition and with an identity*'. In other words, this simply assumes that $S$ is a *monoid*, and that means that an associative binary operation **is defined** on the pair of elements of $S$ (i.e. as a function $S\times S\to S$) and, for elements $a,b\in S$, the result of this operation is denoted by $ab$, and it must be, *by definition*, an element of $S$.